# Events are duplicated when switching months in Fullcalendar v4

Tags: javascript, duplicates, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using Fullcalendar v4 like this. Events are loaded correctly, but when I manually add a new one (it is also saved to SQL database via ajax call), then I change month and return back, this event is rendered twice. I'm not sure what cause this, because when I change months again, event is still doubled only, not trippled.

I've tried set lazyLoading or cache to false and also, for example, remove all events before rendering with `$('.fc-event').remove();` but it did not help.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
  defaultView: 'resourceTimeline30',
  views: {
    resourceTimeline30: {
      type: 'resourceTimeline',
      duration: { days: 30 }
    }
  },
  editable: false,
  selectable: true,
  resources: [ ... ],
  events: 'https://www.example.com/?fullcalendar=load',
  /*
  // did not help
  lazyLoading: true,
  events: {
    url: 'https://www.example.com/?fullcalendar=load',
    cache: false,
    extraParams: function() {
      return {
        cachebuster: new Date().valueOf()
      };
    }
  }
  */
});
calendar.render();
```

Comment: The fact it's doubling could be put down to having the data both in the server-side source (which is called every time the month changes, to get the new events for that month) and having a direct manual entry as well. I suggest making sure you don't mark the manually-added event as persistent.

Comment: Yes, I think the same, but I do not know how to avoid this. You mentioned "do not mark manually-added events as persitent". I googled about that, but did not find any option in FC doc. Could you say more about that idea? Like I wrote, I tried event delete all events with `$('.fc-event').remove();`, but the manually-added events were still there.

Comment: Ok so, this functionality is a implemented slightly differently in fullCalendar 4 and above. I suppose my remark was more aimed at the older version, so I apologise. So please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent and take note of the comments about the `source` parameter - if you either a) use Event Sources and give your event source an ID or b) simply set this value to `true`, you can then associate the manually-added event with that source, then fullCalendar will ensure that next time the events are fetched from the server it will also remove the manually-added copy

Comment: P.S. `$('.fc-event').remove();` won't help because that simply removes the DOM elements used to display the events on-screen. It doesn't remove any events from fullCalendar's internal list of events, so it will simply re-draw all the events next time the calendar and/or events are rendered.

Comment: Well, if I added `true` as a second parameter to `addEvent()`, console gives me an error `There is no source with id "true"`. BUT, when I added ID to my source and used the same ID as a second parameter in `addEvent()`, it seems to work, events are no longer doubled. Many thanks for help, I appreciate that.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I just noticed you are using v4. I checked again, and in v4 you can use an ID, but you can't use `true` - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/Calendar-addEvent vs https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/Calendar-addEvent. I've added the v4 question tag too, so this is more easily searchable for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

So, if anybody needs it, according comments above, the working solution is:

Replace:

```
  events: 'https://www.example.com/?fullcalendar=load',
```

With

```
  eventSources: [{
    'id': 1,
    'url': 'https://www.example.com/?fullcalendar=load'
  }],
```

And use that ID as second parameter in `addEvent()`

```
   calendar.addEvent(event, 1);
```